# Why my input field with required show error as initial state?

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs, input

I have an input field that user need to fill.
When the page is rendered i want the input field to be showing with no error red border because no value has been passed, i want to trigger the error only when the user type some value and then erased it.

#### The behavior that I want

[image: behaviour]

#### The problem, I need to remove this red border on initial render

[image: border]

#### Here is code

```
<div className="ipt-form-group">
      <input type="number" required className={this.state.activeCSS} placeholder="Qual a média de faturamento mensal?" min="0" onInput={this.changeView.bind(this)} onChange={this.changeRevenuesState.bind(this)}/>
    </div>
    <div className="ipt-form-group">
      <input type="number" required className={this.state.activeCSS} placeholder="Qual a média de despesas fixas mensais?" min="0" onInput={this.changeView.bind(this),() => this.callbackFunction()} onChange={this.changeAverageState.bind(this)}/>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We can't help you just from the information above. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to init the validation on `keyup` on your form.
I think you need something like this:

```js
var validationRules = {
  city: {
    message: 'City cannot be empty',
    rule: 'notEmpty'
  },
  address: {
    message: 'Address cannot be empty',
    rule: 'notEmpty'
  }
};

var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');

var values = {};
$inputs.each(function() {
  $(this).on('keyup', function() {
    validation(this, validationRules[this.name]);
  });
});



function validation (input, ruleObj) {
  var isInvalid =  false;

  if (ruleObj.rule === 'notEmpty') {
    if(input.value === '') {
      isInvalid = true;
    } else {
      isInvalid = false;
    }
  }
  if(isInvalid) {
    $(input).addClass('is-invalid');
  } else {
    $(input).removeClass('is-invalid');
  }

  console.log('Validated: ' + input.name);
}
```

```css
.is-invalid {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <label>Address</label>
  <input type="text" name="address">
  <label>City</label>
  <input type="text" name="city">
</form>
```

*(Of course you can replace jQuery. It is bad practice to mix it with react as @Lojka said)*

Comment: he is using reactjs, it is bad practice to mix it with jquery.

Comment: Yes, You've right. It's just an example. You can replace the jQuery.

Comment: You're the best brother! hahaha Worked pretty neat.

Comment: Cool:) if it is working then you can accept my answer

Answer (score -1):

create your component, so it will get `showBorder` property.

then you can create store with it being `false` by default, and after any update change it to `true`

and your store will handle all props for this input

read about flux / redux
https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/in-depth-overview.html#content